# How to express this function efficiently

Tags: c++

```
int f(int n, int mul) {
    if (abs(n)%mul == 0) return n;
    else return f(n - 1, mul);
}
```

So it rounds down to the next `mul`. But obviously isn't good for large values of n. How can it be expressed safely and efficiently?

Comment: the problem is literally a stack overflow ^^ .. scratches head

Comment: Well suited for this forum I thought.

Comment: "obviously isn't good for large values of n" is this true even for `f(2000000000, 1)`? (assuming `int` is 32-bit long)

Comment: May help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884766/recursive-iterative-functions

Comment: Doesn't this, in a way, find the greatest common divisor of the two numbers, or am I mistaken? There are efficient algorithms for that if that's the case.

Answer (score 5):

That's relatively simple, you just evaluate the changing expression while adjusting the variable until the result fulfills the right condition:

```
while (abs(n) % mul != 0) --n;
```

Notes:

- While this answers your question, the code is still bad but for different reasons:

  - There are functions that round numbers. Instead of reinventing the wheel, using one of them should be the first, instinctive approach.
  - `abs()` looks innocent, but what if you give it the smallest possible integer in a twos-complement system? There simply is no absolute value that could be represented as such an integer.
  - Similarly, decrementing `n` could underflow, causing undefined behaviour (and surprising results).
  - Also, what if `mul` is not positive? The code doesn't handle this case in any way, while the function signature allows it.
  - Last but not least, writing a loop in the first place is stupid. A modulo operation will give you the distance of the first operand to the next multiple of the second operand! Make sure you understand how this works on negative numbers though. Also, I wouldn't be surprised if modulo caused undefined behaviour when used with some values. Getting this 99% right is easy, the remaining percent is tricky.
- Compilers that optimize tail end recursion might generate the same code, so it's not guaranteed to give you any advantage.

Comment: **the code is still bad but for different reasons** : they worth mentioning.

Comment: Why is it still bad?

Comment: I wouldn't want to spoil anyone the fun of thinking about it and wouldn't want to do their homework either.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Can you give me clue to cure my curiosity ?

Comment: Actually the question was wrong, I said iteratively when I meant procedurally. I want to know how to express it as efficiently as possible.

Comment: That's trivial, Anonymous Entity.   Think about what the function DOES rather than how you implemented it.

Answer (score 4):

Re

> **”** How can [the recursive function] be expressed safely and efficiently?

For non-negative `n` and `mul`you can just do

```
return n - n%mul;
```

I leave the possible adjustments for negative values, and how to handle a zero `mul`, to the reader.

This is about as efficient as you can get; it's what Euclid would have used, were he alive today and using C++ instead of <sup>[1]</sup>COBOL.

---

An alternative is

```
return mul*(n/mul);
```

Whether that is more or less efficient than the first, depends.

But offhand I would think that any difference would be too small measure.

---

You're not asking for most efficient, but merely “efficient”. Which implies just reasonable efficiency. Still I recommend **measuring**, whenever efficiency is a concern.

Measuring needs not require great effort.

In many cases, just observing that the program performs reasonably well, can be a good enough measurement (of very low resolution and precision, but often good enough).

---

<sup><sup>[1]</sup> Not sure exactly why, but I always think of Euclid as a COBOL guy.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about `StackOverflow` ... then don't!

Following function is basically a `tail recursive` function, compilers like GCC automatically convert it into an iterative function for you!

```
int f(int n, int mul) {
    if (abs(n)%mul == 0) return n;

    return f(n - 1, mul);  //Tail recursion
}
```

REF:

1. [Tail recursion in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693683/tail-recursion-in-c)
2. http://32leav.es/?p=674

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It would only round to a 100 if your second parameter was so. An iterative implementation follows. If you provide further detail I may look at it again.

```
     int f(int n, int mul)
     {
         while(n%mul != 0)
         {
           n--;
         };

     return n;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

What other users have suggested more or less work for limited cases of `n`.

Where is a solution for the general case:

```
if (abs(n) % mul == 0)
    return n;
else if (n >= 0)
    return n - abs(n) % mul;
else
    return mul - abs(n) % mul;
```

or if a oneliner is preferred

```
return abs(n) % mul == 0 ? n : n - (n >= 0 ? abs(n) % mul : mul - abs(n) % mul);
```